# Java: Easy way to get method stub out of class files within a JAR file? Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, class, jar, methods

I'm searching for a way to get a list of method stubs of all classes within a jar file.
I'm not sure where to start... May I use Reflection or Javassist or some other tools of which I've not heard yet!?
At least it may be possible to unpack the jar, decompile the class files and scan with a line parser for methods, but I think that is the most dirtiest way ;-)

Any ideas?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Building upon [aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690118/java-easy-way-to-get-method-stub-out-of-class-files-within-a-jar-file-reflectio/2690440#2690440), you can also use ASM's tree API (as opposed to its visitor API) to parse the contents of the class files contained within your JAR file. As well, you can read the files contained within the JAR file using the [JarFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class. Here is an example of how this could be done:

The `printMethodStubs` method accepts a `JarFile` and proceeds to print out descriptions of all methods contained within all class files.

```
public void printMethodStubs(JarFile jarFile) throws Exception {
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

        String entryName = entry.getName();
        if (entryName.endsWith(".class")) {
            ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();

            InputStream classFileInputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
            try {
                ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(classFileInputStream);
                classReader.accept(classNode, 0);
            } finally {
                classFileInputStream.close();
            }

            System.out.println(describeClass(classNode));
        }
    }
}
```

The `describeClass` method accepts a [`ClassNode`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm32/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/ClassNode.html) object and proceeds to describe it and its associated methods:

```
public String describeClass(ClassNode classNode) {
    StringBuilder classDescription = new StringBuilder();

    Type classType = Type.getObjectType(classNode.name);



    // The class signature (e.g. - "public class Foo")
    if ((classNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC) != 0) {
        classDescription.append("public ");
    }

    if ((classNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE) != 0) {
        classDescription.append("private ");
    }

    if ((classNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_PROTECTED) != 0) {
        classDescription.append("protected ");
    }

    if ((classNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_ABSTRACT) != 0) {
        classDescription.append("abstract ");
    }

    if ((classNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_INTERFACE) != 0) {
        classDescription.append("interface ");
    } else {
        classDescription.append("class ");
    }

    classDescription.append(classType.getClassName()).append("\n");
    classDescription.append("{\n");



    // The method signatures (e.g. - "public static void main(String[]) throws Exception")
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<MethodNode> methodNodes = classNode.methods;

    for (MethodNode methodNode : methodNodes) {
        String methodDescription = describeMethod(methodNode);
        classDescription.append("\t").append(methodDescription).append("\n");
    }



    classDescription.append("}\n");

    return classDescription.toString();
}
```

The `describeMethod` method accepts a [`MethodNode`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm32/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/MethodNode.html) and returns a String describing the method's signature:

```
public String describeMethod(MethodNode methodNode) {
    StringBuilder methodDescription = new StringBuilder();

    Type returnType = Type.getReturnType(methodNode.desc);
    Type[] argumentTypes = Type.getArgumentTypes(methodNode.desc);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> thrownInternalClassNames = methodNode.exceptions;

    if ((methodNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC) != 0) {
        methodDescription.append("public ");
    }

    if ((methodNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_PRIVATE) != 0) {
        methodDescription.append("private ");
    }

    if ((methodNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_PROTECTED) != 0) {
        methodDescription.append("protected ");
    }

    if ((methodNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC) != 0) {
        methodDescription.append("static ");
    }

    if ((methodNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_ABSTRACT) != 0) {
        methodDescription.append("abstract ");
    }

    if ((methodNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_SYNCHRONIZED) != 0) {
        methodDescription.append("synchronized ");
    }

    methodDescription.append(returnType.getClassName());
    methodDescription.append(" ");
    methodDescription.append(methodNode.name);

    methodDescription.append("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < argumentTypes.length; i++) {
        Type argumentType = argumentTypes[i];
        if (i > 0) {
            methodDescription.append(", ");
        }
        methodDescription.append(argumentType.getClassName());
    }
    methodDescription.append(")");

    if (!thrownInternalClassNames.isEmpty()) {
        methodDescription.append(" throws ");
        int i = 0;
        for (String thrownInternalClassName : thrownInternalClassNames) {
            if (i > 0) {
                methodDescription.append(", ");
            }
            methodDescription.append(Type.getObjectType(thrownInternalClassName).getClassName());
            i++;
        }
    }

    return methodDescription.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is great and does exactly what I searched.
Thank you guys!

Comment: Here are all imports, to use this code: `import  java.io.InputStream; import  java.util.Enumeration; import  java.util.List; import  java.util.jar.JarEntry; import  java.util.jar.JarFile; import  org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader; import  org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes; import  org.objectweb.asm.Type; import  org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode; import  org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode; import  xbn.lang.SimpleXbnObject;
`

Comment: I didn't find the good jar to import on web site. Can you help please ? thank you. Yeah i know old post but the question is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is to use the ASM-bytecode framework. Then at least you wouldn't have to go through some decompilation-output with a line-parser. In fact, getting the method-stubs should be like a 20-line implementation of one of their Visitor-interfaces.

I've used it myself for bytecode rewriting and it's fairly simple and straight forward (especially if you're just *reading* the class-files).

http://asm.ow2.org/